# Why ufw is blocking my outgoing traffic?

Tags: networking, server, firewall, iptables

Here is my status:

```
$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (medium)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
```

All outgoing flow are allowed. Now when I am doing:

```
$ wget www.google.com
--2013-07-30 14:28:00--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `www.google.com'
```

What I see in /var/log/kern.log is that the traffic is, indeed, blocked:

```
Jul 30 14:11:27 XXXXXX kernel: [2207680.256415] [UFW BLOCK] IN=lo OUT= MAC=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=62240 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=35323 DPT=53 LEN=40
```

Here is my ufw version:

```
$ sudo ufw version
ufw 0.29.3-1
Copyright 2008-2009 Canonical Ltd.
```

Is explicitly allowing outgoing traffic not enough? How to solve that? Should I add a rule for allowing the loopback interface? How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow established traffic back in.

At the moment your machine is trying to do a DNS lookup for www.google.com but it is never getting the result as the traffic back from the DNS server is being blocked.

Comment: shouldn't that (as well as loopback traffic) be handled by the default before.rules file though? at least that's how it seems to be in ufw 0.31.1-1

Comment: This answer reiterates the problem and doesn't actually answer the question of HOW. I'm also looking for the answer to this

Answer (score 0):

This command helps me solve the issue `sudo ufw allow 53/udp`. Port 53 is the port for DNS.

Comment: The OP's error does indicate that DNS lookups are failing, although I doubt the underlying cause is a firewall rule.

Comment: @DavidFoerster they are, read the kernel message.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I overlooked the `DTP=53`.